# can folium run within anaconda?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, folium

I have been learning Python for a few months now.
on the latest tutorial I have been using folium.
when I import folium into VSCode, the word 'folium' is underlined in red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQoEw.png)

the script runs OK but, when i open VSCode in anaconda, it does not work.
(the script also runs fine within PyCharm).
Sorry for the silly question, I have spent a long time trying to figure out what i have done to cause this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
RWoood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use'`conda list`' to check if the `folium` module is successfully installed in your conda environment.

If there is no `folium` module in the conda list, use'`pip install folium`' to install it. The premise is that the pip is from conda. To check the pip version, you can use'`pip --version`'.

[image]

If there are still squiggles under the'`folium`', please reload VSCode. You could use:`Ctrl+Shift+p`,then input `Developer:Reload Window`.

Note that when using the conda environment, it needs to be in its activated state.like this:

[image]

Reference: [Conda environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments).

Comment: hello Jill Cheng. This has worked, thank you so much :-)